# Pins in standard part supporting multiple packages not connected

Tags: eaglecad, routing, packages

I have two parts on my board that each support multiple packakes so that it easier to find a fitting part. Both are taken from the libraries that came with eagle

- a potentiometer: TRIM_1234-S64YW (TRIM_1234-) (Version 2)
- a capacitor: C-2.5-5/4 (C-) (Version 2)

When I create the board the common pins are not connected, nor can I connect these manually.

[image]

[image]

Of the potentiometer I want pin S and pin S@1 to be connected and of the capacitor pin 2 and 3. Is there an instruction that I can give that tells the router that these are to be connected?

In the schematic I do not see extra pins:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Connections in the schematic (and from there, to the netlist) are what tells the router that pins are to be connected.  Or maybe Eagle allows you to add copper to the footprint if they will always be connected.

Comment: edit: added screenshot from schematic

Comment: Can you change the footprint to have independent pins (which can be connected in the schematic) or add the copper directly to the footprint? Even if Eagle allows the latter it reduces your routing flexibility a bit since it commits to having the trace on a particular layer and of a particular size. I prefer the former solution in Altium and Kicad.

Comment: Your schematic needs to match your desired PCB layout. If the pins don't exist on the schematic then the pads on the PCB are not going to be connected to anything by the netlist.

Comment: In the footprint, give both wiper pins the same number as the wiper pin on the schematic part If Eagle permits multiple pins with the same number (I think Altuim and KiCad do...)

Comment: I resorted to saving the library as a new one and connecting the pins (took some fiddeling). I'm surprised this was not a given, since it is from a library that came with Eagle at installation. Thanks for the advice